# When a value 1 in a list occurs at least three times in a row, how do I output an array where elements = True for those values?

Tags: python

I have a list as follows:

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

I wish to output the following array. When the value 1 occurs at least 3 times in a row, each element in that group of 1's is set to True, i.e.:

```
 [False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group consecutive values in your list. Then check to see if the length of the group is >= 3. If that is the case you need to add `True` "len_" times otherwise you add `False`.

```py
from itertools import groupby

lst = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]

res = []
for _, g in groupby(lst):
    len_ = len(list(g))
    if len_ >= 3:
        res += [True] * len_
    else:
        res += [False] * len_

print(res)
```

output:

```
[False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

As @KellyBundy suggested you can shrink down those four lines of if-statement block into one line like:

```py
res = []
for _, g in groupby(lst):
    len_ = len(list(g))
    res += [len_ >= 3] * len_
```

##### Update after your edit:

```py
from itertools import groupby

lst = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]

res = []
for k, g in groupby(lst):
    len_ = len(list(g))
    res += [len_ >= 3 and k == 1] * len_

print(res)
```

Comment: This also sets groups of 3+ zeros to Trues.

Comment: Also: `res += [len_ >= 3] * len_` :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy I think that's OK if this sets +3 zeros to True since OP said *When **a value** in a list occurs at least three times in a row*.

Comment: @KellyBundy Oh right much more beautiful syntax. I'm gonna add it.

Comment: Yeah I saw the difference between their question text and title only afterwards, asked about it then.

Comment: Apologies, I meant to say "When a value 1 in a list" in the title! I presume for this case, I could just adjust the line to: res += [len_ >= 3 and _ == 1] * len_? :)

Comment: @fandango_jones Yes that's true. I just edited the answer and rename `_` to `k` since normally we use `_` to indicate we're ignoring it.